# UITableview prototype cell not populating properly

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to populate a UITableView prototype cell with "Facebook status". It has images and videos depending on the response from Facebook server. But I am not able to populate it properly.

I will get the first image from the array. But when I scroll down UITableView and reach the top again, the image disappears. And when I print the value of `i` it exceeds the count of array soon after the tableview is loaded.

I am adding the edited code here.

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

```
    var rows : Int = 0
    if section < numberOfRowsAtSection.count{
        rows = numberOfRowsAtSection[section]
        print(section,rows)
    }
    return rows
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    print("Section,Row",indexPath.section, indexPath.row)
    switch(combinedArray[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]){
    case "photo" :
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ImageDetail", for:indexPath) as! imageCell
            if(im < imageDetails.count){
                let imageUrl = imageDetails[im]
                let url = URL(string:imageUrl)
                let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url!)
                cell.storyDetailsLbl1.text = photoStoryDetails[im]
                print(imageDetails[im])
                cell.images1.image = UIImage(data: data!)
            }
            im = im + 1

            return cell

    case "video" :
            let cell1 = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "VideoCell", for: indexPath) as! videoPlayerCell
            cell1.videoView.isHidden = false
            if  vd < videoURLs.count{
                print(videoURLs.count)
                let urls = videoURLs[vd]
                cell1.videoPlayerItem = AVPlayerItem.init(url: urls)
                cell1.videoLabel.text = videoStoryDetails[vd]
            }
            vd = vd + 1

            return cell1

    case "link":
            let cell2 = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "LinkCell", for: indexPath) as! linkCell
            if  ln < linkDetails.count {
                cell2.linkLbl.text = linkDetails[ln]
            }
            ln = ln + 1
            return cell2

    default:
             let cell3 = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "StatusCell", for: indexPath) as! statusCell
                if  st < statusDetails.count{
                    cell3.statusLbl.text = statusDetails[st]
                }
                st = st + 1
                return cell3
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tableviews deque already created cells and reuse them to enhance performance.  So a cell with the identifier "ImageDetail" could be reused and populated with data from any of your case statements.  This will cause oddities like images disappearing when they shouldn't.

One way to solve this is to ensure you are handling each cell property in every case. `cell.storyDetailsLbl1.text` isn't handled in the `photo` case. `cell.images1.image` isn't handled in the `link` case, etc.

Better would be to define a cell with a unique identifier for each one of your cases.  i.e.  `PhotoCell`, `LinkCell`, `VideoCell`, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I defined different cells for each case. And now I'm able to populate the tableview with different values. But I still have a problem.The  index path.row is giving these values                                   0
1
2
3
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10

Comment: is it beacuse I'm using  4 sections in my UITableView.? So my typedetails[indexpath.row] is not giving  appropriate values. How to get the values from type details in order. I tried using an index for the array with if condition like                 if ( i  < type details.count) . But it affects the cell which will be returned from this function.

Comment: Yes, each section will have it's row index restart at 0.  If your data source is a single array and you're using sections, you'll want to use an array within an array.  i.e. `text = model[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]`. Better yet would be to use a custom `struct` so you can do something like `model = models[indexPath.section]; text = model.someText`

Comment: Thanks again. I used multidimensional array and now the index path.row is giving values in order.

Comment: I have included my edited code.Now my table view is repeating values after every 3 rows. But the array from which I'm populating is having correct values.

Comment: @ShobhaVJ You can contact me at frankie at fbombmedia dot com and maybe I can assist further.